# Using StringExpression in file name

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to open the file "myfile.cdf" or "myfile.nb".  One or the other will be in the directory but not both.  Because I don't know which, I'm trying to use `StringExpression` to be general about opening the file.  Here is the code below.  It does't seem to work.  Ideas?

```
NotebookOpen[NotebookDirectory[]<>"myfile." ~~ __]
```

Comment: That did It! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
NotebookOpen[First@FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myfile.*"]]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Been away from Mathematica for awhile.  I can't believe I forgot this.

Answer (score 2):

StringExpression, like all patterns, are template which can be matched against.  They don't automagically expand to match eveything--you do some function to do that.  I'd write your code like this

```
NotebookOpen[First[FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test." <> # & /@ {"cdf", "pdf"}]]]
```

This will give you a list of the 0, 1 or 2, files which match the two names, and no others.  Of course, it will error if there are no matches (which you'll need to handle), but this also allows you to control which of the two files to prefer if both are present, just be reordering the list of extensions.

---

Expansion:  Since the first thing I wrote had so many typos, here's a bonus answer based on the same idea, which is probably how I'd write this.  The code to find the files is the same, but rather than naively taking `First`, I use `Replace`.  If the result is a list of one or more file names, I open the first one (which will return a `NotebookObject` pointing to what was just opened).  Otherwise, I return `$Failed`.  The code following the assignment can check `result` and decide what to do...

```
result = Replace[
   FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myfile." <> # & /@ {"cdf", "nb"}],
   {
      {file_String, ___} :> NotebookOpen[file],
      _ -> $Failed
   }
]
```

Comment: Missing `/@` in between the function and the list.

Comment: Also, too many periods in file file paths generated; e.g., 'myfile..nb'

Comment: You should test your code before you post it.

Comment: Yes. I can't seem to get this code to work even with the changes.

Comment: Note sure what I pasted in there, because it certainly wasn't right (and I did test the code, only I used files I actually have on my filesystem).  This code show now work.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be reasonably robust. You can even use wildcard * in the name string, but in that case you will open the file which is 1st match in the list returned by `FileNames`.

```
openNBorCDF[name_String] :=
  Module[{pathNames, file},
    pathNames =
      FileNames[{name <> ".nb", name <> ".cdf"}, NotebookDirectory[]];
    file = First[pathNames, Return[$Failed]];
    NotebookOpen[file];
    file]
```

On my system, evaluating

```
openNBorCDF["test"]
```

in a notebook loaded from the Desktop directory opens `test.cdf` and returns

> `"/Users/oldmg/Desktop/test.cdf"`

while evaluating

```
openNBorCDF["foo"]
```

opens nothing and returns

> `$Failed`

because neither `foo.nb` nor `foo.cdf` exists in my Desktop directory.

#### Edit

The above code requires V10.3 or later. Those with earlier versions of Mathematica should try this:

```
openNBorCDF[name_String] :=
  Module[{pathNames, file},
   pathNames =
     FileNames[{name <> ".nb", name <> ".cdf"}, NotebookDirectory[]];
   If[pathNames === {}, Return[$Failed], file = pathNames[[1]]];
   NotebookOpen[file];
   file]
```

Comment: @MichaelMcCain. I used a form of `First` that only became available in V10.3. Are you using an earlier version?